# hide initial 3d transform animation

Tags: javascript, css, css-transforms

I have set up an animated card flip [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kiwitotoro/JeYu5/6/) which happens on button click. It is set up using Modernizr to test for the feature then enable the 3d styling if the feature is available. if you press the run button you will see the back panel rotate 180 degrees on page load, is there a way to disable this?
It does not happen if the styles are set from the start but I am enabling them later for compatibility (if you enable the "&& false" in the javascript you will see the alternate view for browsers without the 3d transform).
HTML:

```
<div id="card-container">
    <button id="card-flip">Flip the card</button>
    <div id="card">
        <div class="front card-surface"><!-- front -->
            <p>The front</p>
        </div>
        <div class="back card-surface"><!-- back -->
            <p>The back</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
if(Modernizr.csstransitions && Modernizr.csstransforms3d /* && false */ ){
    var flipButton = document.getElementById('card-flip');
flipButton.style.display = 'block';
    var cardContainer = document.getElementById('card-container');
    cardContainer.className = cardContainer.className + " threed";
    flipButton.addEventListener("click", flipfunction,false); // flipfunction toggles .flip class
}
```

CSS is on jsfiddle

Comment: Are you looking for something like [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/JeYu5/7/)? I have just applied the transition to the `back` only when the card has `flip`. This would mean initially it wouldn't do any transform as it has no `flip` on load.

Comment: Set the classname in HTML, add only the event listener in Javascript

Comment: @Harry That was it, I was looking at that code for too long :) add as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: @vals I add the class in Javascript as I am testing for compatibility. If a browser does not have the 3d transform etc. it will show the front and back of the card above each other. (It's a browser compatibility thing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid the card flipping effect on page load by setting the transition to the element with `class='back'` only when the parent `#card` element has the `class='flip'`.

On page load, the `class='flip'` would not be present and hence the effect would not applied.

Change the code from

```css
.threed #card .card-surface{
    background-color:$base-white;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    width: 280px;
    height: 180px;
    padding:10px;
}
```

to

```css
.threed #card .front{ /* This is to apply the transition to the front element */
    background-color:$base-white;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    width: 280px;
    height: 180px;
    padding:10px;
}
.threed #card.flip .back{ /* This is to apply transition to the back element only when parent has flip class */
    background-color:$base-white;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    width: 280px;
    height: 180px;
    padding:10px;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/w7KCT/)